# How to search/list for all files starting with dot (.) but .htaccess is excluded from the list

Tags: ssh

Using SSH command line, I need to **delete** all the files starting with dot (.) but I don't want to delete .htaccess files.

I tried so far to list them like this

```
find . -type f -name ".*"
```

It listed all the files properly.but .htaccess was there too.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `!` (or, in GNU `find`, `-not`) to logically invert a test. From `man find`:

```
   ! expr True  if  expr  is false.  This character will also usually need
          protection from interpretation by the shell.

   -not expr
          Same as ! expr, but not POSIX compliant.
```

So

```
find . -type f -name ".*" ! -name .htaccess
```

or

```
find . -type f -name ".*" -not -name .htaccess
```

Ex. given

```
$ find . -type f -name ".*"
./.bar
./.baz
./.foo
./.htaccess
```

then

```
$ find . -type f -name ".*" ! -name .htaccess -delete
```

leaving

```
$ find . -type f -name ".*"
./.htaccess
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I want to delete the list after I show it . ofcourse I don't want to delete the .htacess Thanks a lot again

Comment: It worked, Thank you so much for your help